# Angular click directive scroll to section of page within modal-dialog not working with dynamic content

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular9, angular2-directives, angularjs-ng-click

Looking to scroll to page sections when user clicks using scrollIntoView in a modal with dynamic content.

I've tried using ViewChild, event emitting, and ngAfterViewChecked but no luck.

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-modals-bdg1bh?file=src/app/modal-container/modal-container.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem. for me the solution was change (click) events to onclick and write typescript scroll functions in script tag.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-modals-6jtnrm?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-container%2Fmodal-container.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a working solution. But wondering if we could get it working in the component itself and the script written in the component without a script tag.

Comment: i think we cant use angular syntax after compile and browser obviously cant understand that. we have to use pure html javascript when we add them straight to dom.